# strip out an part of an link

Tags: php

i've a pagination code in my project

but the problem is in the links

i get in links something like `post?pid=2&page=2&page=3%page=6`

I am trying to strip out the `page`

Here is an example

```
site.com/post.php?pid=12&page=10
site.com/category.php?cid=120&page=2
```

I am trying to get this results

```
site.com/post.php?pid=12
site.com/category.php?cid=120
```

Comment: so what is the code you have written for this?

Comment: @Satya There is no require for code to ask!!! i know the idea but i don't know how to do it, i did not write any code, because i am beginner in reguler expressions, or i would not be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to do something like that would be to use regular expressions.

You could use preg_replace to replace whatever looks like &page=something by an empty string.

This should work :

```
$result = preg_replace("/&page=[0-9]*/i","",$initialurl);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly, but it works only for numbers what if i want use if for &page=1sdaf3, i am sorry i don't know for expressions